# How to work around string splitting while loading a list from a file in QT

Tags: ifstream, qlistwidget

I'm trying to create a simple "To Do list" app in QT Creator while coding the part that loads and saves the list from a file I get stuck on a problem.

If you enter a string like "Do my homework" the program threads the string as it should, but when you load the program again the save file got split in words. So it gets all the entries but each word separated ("Do", "my", "homework").

What is the solution? I tried working with 'char arrays' and 'getline' but they give me nothing but errors.

Here is my code for the save and load parts:

```
void MainWindow::LoadList(){
    std::ifstream load_file("./data.bin");
    char loader[255];
    while (load_file >> loader){
        QString Writer = QString::fromStdString(loader);
        ui->lstTaskList->addItem(Writer);
    }
}

void MainWindow::SaveList(){
    std::ofstream save_file("./data.bin");
    for (auto i = 0; i < ui->lstTaskList->count(); i++){
        QString Saver = ui->lstTaskList->item(i)->text();
        std::string saver = Saver.toStdString();
        save_file << saver << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this, please?

My thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The anwser was using QFile and QByteArray for me, I knew about QFile but it tries using basic "std" c++ till I learned more about QT.